# Join queries are not working as expected when trying to compare a count result with a value

Tags: mysql, join, query

I'm learning `SQL` from a book and I'm trying to do some exercices on `join queries`. The only problem that I'm facing is that all of my join queries are not working while they seem well.

These are the tables:

```
    students(student_id,student_names,student_age)
    courses_students(course_id,student_id)
    courses(course_id,course_schedule,course_room,teacher_id)
    teachers(teacher_id,teacher_names)
```

The query is "which courses have more than 5 students enrolled?"

Here is what I've done:

```
select 
  course_name,
  count(select count(*) from courses) as count 
from students,courses,courses_students 
where students.student_id = courses_students.student_id,
courses.course_id = courses_students.course_id 
and count > 5
```

And the other one is "what are the names of students enrolled in at least 2 courses scheduled for the same hours?"

My query:

```
select student_name,schedule 
from students,courses,courses_students 
where students.student_id = courses_students.student_id,
courses.course_id = courses_students.course_id 
and count > 2
```

Comment: 1) Aggregate functions (COUNT() in your case) needs in GROUP BY clause; 2) The conditions in WHERE clause must be combined using logical operators (AND, OR), not by comma; 2) Output field name (`count` in your case) cannot be used in WHERE clause, it can be used in HAVING clause.

Comment: In `JOIN` queries, please qualify each column with the table it comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question 
"which courses have more than 5 students enrolled?"

try the following query

```
select a.course_id,b.course_name,count(a.student_id) as student_count from courses_students a join courses b on a.course_id=b.course_id group by a.course_id having student_count>5;
```

For the second question
"what are the names of students enrolled in at least 2 courses scheduled for the same hours"

try this

```
select a.student_id,a.student_name,b.course_schedule,count(b.course_id) as course_count from students a join courses b join courses_students c on b.course_id=c.course_id and a.student_id=b.student_id group by a.student_id,b.course_schedule having course_count>1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start with:

```
SELECT course_id
FROM courses_students
GROUP BY course_id
HAVING COUNT(student_id) > 5
```

The result of this query is a new relation (table, derived table), which you can use as any other table. Let's call this corses_5_students

```
SELECT c.*
FROM courses as c
JOIN (
    SELECT course_id
    FROM courses_students
    GROUP BY course_id
    HAVING COUNT(student_id) > 5
) AS corses_5_students
    ON corses_5_students.course_id = c.course_id
```